# Null check before concat multiple collections

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code each of the collections inherit from MyCollection

```
var result = MyCollectionA.Concat(MyCollectionB.Concat(MyCollectionC
             .Concat<MyCollection>(MyCollectionD)));
```

what is the best way to check if each is no null before doing the concat?  I know I could write out a big if else block but wondering is there a better approach

Comment: By far the best approach is to keep the invariant that no collection may ever be `null`, and any place that might attempt to produce `null` is forced to produce an empty collection instead -- *before* any operation on it. This saves on code like you wouldn't believe.

Comment: Roll on nullable reference types!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a helper method `EmptyIfNull` and check if the collection is null there, if so return `Enumerable.Empty<MyCollection>`. Then the code would become:

```
MyCollectionA.EmptyIfNull()
             .Concat(MyCollectionB.EmptyIfNull())
             .Concat(MyCollectionC.EmptyIfNull());
```

Ofcourse you can prefer a shorter name if you wish.

`EmptyIfNull` could be declared like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) 
{
    return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the null-coalescing operator and `Enumerable.Empty`:

```
var result = MyCollectionA.Concat(MyCollectionB ?? Enumerable.Empty<MyClass>())
                          .Concat(MyCollectionB ?? Enumerable.Empty<MyClass>())
                          .Concat(MyCollectionC ?? Enumerable.Empty<MyClass>())
                          .Concat(MyCollectionD ?? Enumerable.Empty<MyClass>())
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to muck around with extension methods. The easiest and shortest way is this:

```
var result =
    new [] { MyCollectionA, MyCollectionB, MyCollectionC, MyCollectionD }
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Concat();
```

Comment: Get the error - No best type found for implicitly-typed array - The collections are type ReadOnlyCollection

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat - That would be the kind of information that you'd put in the question. Can you please edit your question with the types of the collections and their associated classes?